# validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i don't know why i'm receiving this warning? and because of this i can't see updated table..

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>.
```

In some cases I saw that it is about some white spaces and different table tags, but I don't see how this applies in here.

**TableCom**

```
import { Paper, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow } from '@material-ui/core'
import React from 'react'

export const Countries = ({details}) => {
    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table aria-label="simple table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                    <TableCell align='right'>Country</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align='right'>Total Infected</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align='right'>Total Recoverd</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align='right'>Total Deaths</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {details.length && details.map((detail) => {
                        return (
                      <TableRow>
                          <td key={detail.id}>{detail.cases}</td> : null
                      </TableRow>
                        );
                    })}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    )
}
```

**App.js** for state and passing props

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Appbar } from './components/pageOne/Appbar'
import { Cards } from './components/pageOne/Cards'
import { fetchData, fetchCountries } from './components/FetchDataFromApi'
import { Countries } from './components/pageOne/TableCom'

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const fetchAPI = await fetchCountries();
        setDetails(fetchAPI)
      })()
      }, []);

  useEffect(() => {

    (async () => {
      const fetchedData = await fetchData();
      setData(fetchedData)
      
    })()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
    <Appbar />
    <Cards data = {data} />
    <Countries details = {details} />
    
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

any solution to solve this...  [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-goldwasser-xch0n?file=/src/TableCom.js)

Comment: Just looking at this briefly, it looks like you're tring to do a ternary, but you're not doing a ternary. For example, you have ": null" in <td key={detail.id}>{detail.cases}</td> : null

Comment: i added this null after getting this warninng but this is not working, and initially i am not using html tag <td>, instead of this i used material-ui TableCell.

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox with a reproducible case? The way you have it, you should be actually seeing the text ": null" in your html because it's not a ternary.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `TableCell` instead of `td`? Because you use tableCell in the head, maybe it has something to do with material-ui.

Comment: i have used that too, and after that i think may be it should work but it did't

Comment: i am making codesandbox please check it

Comment: Provide a link in the original question

Comment: @sultan as mentioned in my previous comments, it's the : null thing you had. Get rid of it and the problem will go away. Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-raman-2z33w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @jas7457 [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-goldwasser-xch0n?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @jas7457 i'm fetching data from API which is an object and in that object it is an array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you handle the response which you're getting from the api. You're returning an object instead of an array.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-dan-7iusu

Here is a working sandbox, I just get all the data from the response and pass it down. You can also create an array yourself, only with the data you need. But currently you're passing an object.

Look at `index.js` in `fetchApi`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have checked that its now working perfectly and and trying to better myself in javascript

Comment: You can approve this as the answer then.

Comment: yeah, one small issue is still there that why some countries stats for recovered cases is not showing in the table, is that a thing inside javascript

Comment: @sultan the `recovered` field is null, so it's ан issue with the data. For example for UK.
For these entries you can do something like `{detail.recovered ?? "Data missing"}`